# Javascript File Render store key into onload method?

Tags: javascript, arrays

i want to store a key into array.

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.uploadedImages.length; i++) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var vm = this;
    reader.onload = function(e,i) {
        var imageSrc = e.target.result;
        vm.items.push( {image : imageSrc,index : i} );
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
}
```

How to store i into index key in items array.

Right now i passed 4 element into this.uploadedImages array when i checked items array it's store 3 into all elements like.

```
{ {image : 'path',index : 3},{image : 'path',index : 3},
  {image : 'path',index : 3},{image : 'path',index : 3} }
```

i want like this

```
{ {image : 'path',index : 0},{image : 'path',index : 1},
  {image : 'path',index : 2},{image : 'path',index : 3} }
```

how to do this please help thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a closure issue here.

The `onload` callback is executed after the loop ends while the `i` var has it's last value of 3.

A quick and dirty solution is to wrap the callback function with another function that runs during the loop iteration and creates a var with the current value.

```
reader.onload = function(idx){ 
        return function(e) {
            var imageSrc = e.target.result;
            vm.items.push( {image : imageSrc,index : idx} );
    }}(i)
```

Check this similar [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vLhaqhtw/) example.